# Overloaded Bool/String Ambiguity

Tags: c++, string, casting, boolean, overloading

Why is C++ casting the string literal I pass in as a bool rather than a string?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A(string v)
        {
            cout << v;
        }

        A(bool v)
        {
            cout << v;
        }
};

int main()
{
    A("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `1`

Is it because the compiler isn't smart enough to make the jump from char * to string and rather just assumes that bool is the closest thing to a pointer? Is my only option to make an explicit char * constructor that basically does the exact same thing as the string constructor?

Comment: I generally prefer explicit conversions. Implicit conversions have gotchas like this. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2346083/10077

Comment: I'm not sure but: Both conversions are possible (converting pointer to bool checks for null pointer). But converting to bool is a *built-in* conversion, while to string is a *user-defined* convesion (via implicit c'tor). And now if I remember correctly, built-ins have more priority over user defined ones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Method overload not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770252/c-method-overload-not-working)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have C++11 you can use a delegating constructor:

```c++
A(char const* s) : A(std::string(s)) { }
```

The reason the boolean converting-constructor is chosen over the one for `std::string` is because the conversion from `char const*` to `bool` is a standard conversion while the one to `std::string` is a user-defined conversion. Standard conversions have a greater rank than user-defined conversions.

Answer (score 5):

With

```
A(string("hello"));
```

it will give the expected result.

**Why is it so ?**

It's because of the standard conversions:

- "hello" is understood as a `const char*` pointer
- this pointer can be converted to a `bool` (section 4.12 of the standard: *"A prvalue of (...) pointer (...) type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool."* )
- the conversion from "hello" to `string` is not considered because section 12.3 of standard explains that "*Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined conversions*" and "*User-defined conversions are applied only where they are unambiguous*".  Wouldn't you have the `bool` constructor the `std::string` conversion would be done implicitely.

**How to get what you expected ?**

Just add the missing constructor for string litterals:

```
A(const char* v)
{
    cout << v;  // or convert v to string if you want to store it in a string member
}
```

*Of course, instead of rewriting a constructor from scratch, you could opt for a delegate as suggested by 0x499602D2 in another answer.*

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to type out `string(...)` every time. Is my only other option to create a constructor that takes a `char const *` as an argument?

Comment: Yes ! i've completed with additional explanations.

Answer (score 4):

Recently I passed this problem too, let me share another way.

You can change the `bool` constructor to a `unsigned char`. So the decay and implict conversion of string literal don't happen, and the `std::string` constructor takes place.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(string v)
    {
        cout << v;
    }

    A(unsigned char v)
    {
        cout << static_cast<bool>(v);
    }
};

int main()
{
     A("Hello"); // <- Call A(string)
     A(false);   // <- Call A(unsigned char)
}
```

This way you don't need to provide always overloads to `std::string` and `const char*` neither making code bloat constructing the `std::string` at the client call site.

I don't claim that's better, but it's simpler.

Comment: I had the same problem, but I'm wondering though why A("Hello"); does not give a warning, but const char *b = "Hello"; A(b); gives warning 4800: forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false'?

Comment: This also worked for me and is also extremely useful with the new `string_view`s. See [here](https://godbolt.org/g/1uCwR2) for an example.

Comment: This is a very useful and pragmatic answer. This answer helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

When selecting an overloaded method this is the order that the compiler tries:

1. Exact match
2. Promotion
3. Standard numerical conversion
4. User defined operators

A pointer doesn't promote to `bool` but it does convert to `bool`. A `char*` uses an `std` operator to convert to `std::string`. Note that if `char*` used the same number in this list to convert to *both* `bool` and `std::string` it would be ambiguous which method the compiler should choose, so the compiler would throw an "ambiguous overload" error.

I would throw my weight behind [0x499602D2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701092/0x499602d2)'s solution. If you have C++11 your best bet is to call: `A(char* s) : A(std::string(s)){}`
If you don't have C++11 then I would create an `A(char* s)` constructor and abstract the logic of the `A(std::string)` constructor into a method and call that method from both constructors.

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/76-function-overloading/