# Overloading, variadic functions and bool type

Tags: c++, c++11

Following program compiles fine and works as expected. Its output is:

> 1
>   2

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo
{
public:
  void Bar(const char* b, ...) { printf("1\n"); };
  void Bar(int a, const char* b, ...) { printf("2\n"); };
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo1;
  foo1.Bar("Test", "xx", 1, 2);
  foo1.Bar(1, "xx", "xx", 2, 2);
}
```

Now if I change the `int` parameter of the second `Bar` function into `bool` and `foo1.Bar(1, "xx", "xx", 2, 2);` into `foo1.Bar(true, "xx", "xx", 2, 2);`, then the following line won't compile and I get the error: `'Foo::Bar': 2 overloads have similar conversions`:

```
  foo1.Bar("Test", "xx", 1, 2);
```

The whole program that doesn't compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo
{
public:
  void Bar(const char* b, ...) { printf("1\n"); };
  void Bar(bool a, const char* b, ...) { printf("2\n"); };
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo1;
  foo1.Bar("Test", "xx", 1, 2);  // error: 'Foo::Bar': 2 overloads have similar conversions
  foo1.Bar(true, "xx", "xx", 2, 2);
}
```

I don't understand why there is an ambiguity in the second case.

**EDIT**

But if pointers implicitly convert to `bool`, why does following compile ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo
{
public:
  void Bar(const char* b) { printf("1\n"); };
  void Bar(bool a) { printf("2\n"); };
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo1;
  foo1.Bar("Test");
  foo1.Bar(true);
}
```

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413951/overloaded-bool-string-ambiguity

Comment: This has nothing to do with variadic functions whatsoever, which you'd have discovered had you constructed a _minimal_ testcase.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just edited the question and added a minimal test case without variadic functions that compiles...

Comment: @robor78 the question is similar but not the same. Here we have `const char*` which is a _builtin type_, whereas in the other question there is a `string`  which is a _user defined type_.

Comment: (Add headers and namespaces please. You should know by now, at 11.9k rep, how to form a [MCVE].)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sorry I forgot  `#include <stdio.h>`. Apart from that it _was_ minimal and verifiable. And no need for namespaces here (at least with my environnment, Microsoft VS2015).

Comment: Nitpicking now but prefer to code to standards rather than relying on implementation specifics, so `std::printf` or a suitable `using namespace` declaration would be appropriate! Anyway, as to the answer to your question, meh dunno. Would have to delve deeper into function overload selection mechanics than I feel like right now ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you match `"Test", "xx", 1, 2` against `const char*, ...`, the conversion sequence for the first argument has exact match rank, the second through fourth one are ellipsis conversion sequences. So (exact match, ellipsis, ellipsis, ellipsis).

When you match `"Test", "xx", 1, 2` against `bool, const char*, ...`, the first conversion sequence for the first argument has conversion rank; the second is an exact match, the third and fourth are ellipsis conversion sequences. In other words, (conversion, exact match, ellipsis, ellipsis).

Exact match beats conversion; everything beats ellipsis (see [[over.ics.rank]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.ics.rank)). Thus we have a so-called criss-cross situation here where one function has a better conversion sequence for one argument and the other function has a better conversion sequence for another argument. Since a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for a function to be better than another function is that none of the conversion sequences are worse than those of the other function ([[over.match.best]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.best#1)), neither of those two functions is better than the other.

Answer (score 5):

This is fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo
{
public:
  void Bar(const char* b, ...) { printf("1\n"); };
  void Bar(bool a, ...) { printf("2\n"); };
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  foo.Bar("Test");
}
```

This is not fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Foo
{
public:
  void Bar(const char* b, ...) { printf("1\n"); };
  void Bar(bool a, char another, ...) { printf("2\n"); };
};

int main()
{
  Foo foo;
  foo.Bar("Test", 'c');  // Ambiguous!
}
```

In the first case, the first version of Bar() is clearly better. But in the second case, it is not so clear anymore because, while the first version has a better match for parameter 1, the second version has a better match for parameter 2.

The remaining question is: why does using 'int' instead of 'bool' avoid the ambiguity? The answer is that a pointer may implicitly convert to bool but not int.

Comment: I edited the question: so why is the last case fine ?

Comment: Your newly added case is equivalent to the first case in my answer: if you call with 'const char*', the version of Bar() that takes 'const char*' is clearly better; and if you call with 'bool', the version of Bar() that takes 'bool' is clearly better. An implicit conversion is still a conversion. A function that does not need to convert its argument, if exists, takes precedence.