# boost::variant with bool and string

Tags: c++, boost

I'm having trouble with `boost::variant` (using boost 1.67.0).

When my template parameter list includes both `bool` and `std::string`, any variant objects which should be treated as string, seem to be implicitly bound to bool instead. For example:

```
using Varval = boost::variant<bool, std::string>;

void main()
{
    std::vector<Varval> vect{ true, false, "Hello_World" };

    std::cout << "[ ";
    for (const auto &v : vect)
        std::cout << v << "  ";
    std::cout << "]\n";
}
```

Outputs:

> [ 1  0  1 ]

whereas if I change nothing but the first template argument, from `bool` to `int`, it works fine:

```
using Varval = boost::variant<int, std::string>;

void main()
{
    std::vector<Varval> vect{ true, false, "Hello_World" };

    std::cout << "[ ";
    for (const auto &v : vect)
        std::cout << v << "  ";
    std::cout << "]\n";
}
```

Properly outputs:

> [ 1  0  Hello_World ]

Any ideas?

Comment: "Hello_World" is not a `string`. its a `const char*`

Comment: "Hello_World" is not a `const char*`, it's a `char[12]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::variant` has one constructor overload for each stated type. In your first example there will be one overload for `bool` and one for `std::string`. You are now calling the constructor with a `char[n]` which can be imlicitly converted to both of them. So there is no perfect match but two candidates. But instead of telling you that the call is ambiguous, the compiler will choose the `bool` overload as the better match.

Why? That is already perfectly answered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14770252/9883438).

In your second example with `int` and `std::string` you are passing `bool`s and `char[n]` to the constructors. `bool` is implicitly convertable to `int` but not to `std::string`. `char[n]` is implicitly convertable to `std::string` but not to `int`. So the according constructors are called as there is only one candidate for each.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.