# prevent string literals from being converted to bool versus std::string

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

Similar questions have been asked before, such as [String literal matches bool overload instead of std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770252/string-literal-matches-bool-overload-instead-of-stdstring).

But what I want to know is what should C++ developers do to prevent this from happening?  As someone who writes C++ libraries for others to consume, what should I do to ensure this doesn't happen?  Here is the example I ran into today, where a library had 2 `initialize()` methods:

```
void initialize(bool someflag) { /* ... */ }
void initialize(const std::string & name) { /* ... */ }
```

Now the problematic code was in the application that wanted to utilize this functionality and which called it in a manner similar to this:

```
initialize("robert");
```

At first glance you'd think that this would call `initialize(string)` but it actually calls the first `initialize(bool)` with a boolean flag set to true!

Yes, I know it can be fixed with this:

```
initialize( std::string("robert") );
```

But this puts the onus on the caller.

---

Edit for @zdan:  I didn't consider the "solutions" in the other linked question to be great solutions since 1) I was hoping not to have to add a `const char *` version of every method that takes a bool or string, and 2) the template solution increases the maintainability of the code significantly for affected methods, renders them almost unreadable.

Comment: If you want to *prevent* it, you can `delete` the specific overload. For example `void initialize(const char*) = delete;`. You'll get a compiler error if you pass a string literal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String literal matches bool overload instead of std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770252/string-literal-matches-bool-overload-instead-of-stdstring)

Comment: A hacky way to fix it would be to add `template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, bool>>>` to your `bool` overload

Comment: Changing the signature to `void initialize(bool& someflag)` makes it less sticky with pointers, but then it won't bind to a `true` or `false` literal value.

Comment: @zdan You serious?  Did you even read the question?

Comment: Yup. The answer is in the question you reference (it's not the accepted answer)

Comment: The onus will either be on the caller (`initialize("robert"s)` if your compiler is new enough), or on the developer (you).  Adding in the `const char *` overloads is less error prone and less work (longterm).  There isn't a non-invasive solution that will automagically fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what should I do to ensure this doesn't happen?

One possibility is to create an overload that accepts a `char const*` and make it a pass through to the overload that accepts a `std::string`.

```
void initialize(char const* name) { initialize(std::string(name)); }
```